# Looping the table elements in jQuery through all input fields of a specific class

Tags: jquery, loops, html-table

Here I want to loop each input field of a table and filter out the fields with specific input-field-class. I know how to loop within all input fields of a table, i.e. :

```
$('#table_id :input').each(function(key) {
}
```

Now I need to know how I can further loop these input fields with a specific if. Let that Class be '.input-class'

Comment: Id's have to be unique -> no loop required: `$("#input-special").val()`

Comment: @Andreas yes you are right. So I am changing it to class. How can I iterate through a specific class now?

Comment: Just select the elements by class to begin with ... you kinda wrote it yourself already, _"Let that Class be '.input-class'"_ - yeah, well, that's not actually a class, but a class _selector_ already. So where exactly is the problem now?

Comment: Or do you still want to loop over _all_ fields, but treat these ones differently? Well then check with `.hasClass()` inside a condition.

Comment: @CBroe so right now I have bunch of input fields in a table with id = #table_id. Now I want to iterate through those filtered input fields which have a class='input-class'

Comment: Again: Then "filter" those right away, via the selector you are using inside `$()`

Comment: @CBroe and what will that be?

Comment: Well something like `$('#table_id :input.input-class')` or similar …?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example. You just want to use the class to get the `<input>` elements that have the class `input-class` and push it to the array.

Code below will only return rows that have the class: `input-class`

```js
//create inputs array
var inputValues = [];

//for each table row
$("#table_id tr").each(function()
{
  //get input value
  var inputValue = $(this).find(".input-class").val();
  
  //if not empty push to array
  if(inputValue !='undefined' && inputValue !=null )
    inputValues.push(inputValue);
});

//output all input values stored in array
console.log("All Filtered Rows:");
console.log(inputValues);
```

```css
.dont-filter{
  background: white;
}

.input-class{
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_id">
  <tr><th>row id</th><th>column 1</th><th>column 2</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="input-class" value="row id 1"> 1
</td><td>row 1</td><td>row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="input-class" value="row id 2"> 2
</td><td>row 2</td><td>row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="dont-filter" value="row id 3"> 3
</td><td>row 3</td><td>row 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```